# Some text distorts when changed by JS function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've built a calculator that estimates the cost of my client service. The calculator works with HTML range slider, that triggers a function when the value is changed. The function run some calculations and updates certain div's HTML with the result using jQuery.

At first the text looks fine but if the user is using Safari, when the result changes and the div's content updates, the text distorts like so: 

[image]

I've tried to change the div's height, but as you can see the height of the div is not the problem:

[image]

This is what I have:

```html
<div class="hex-result" id="hex-result1">
</div>
```

```css
.hex-result{
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 17px 0px 4px 0px;
}
```

```
val1 = $("#range-1").val();
val2 = $("#range-2").val();
val3 = $("#range-3").val();    

hex1Total = val1 * val2 * val3;
if (isNaN(hex1Total)) hex1Total = 0;
$("#hex-result1").html(numberWithCommas(hex1Total));
```

Comment: Can you reproduce that error in other browsers? To me, this looks like a browser bug.

Comment: Without a [mcve] is is not possible to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another day of research I've found that the problem was with the line height.

So here is the css that works:

```css
.hex-result{
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin: 17px 0px 4px 0px;
}
```